# RecordRTC: Interval upload to Web Server video files cannot be played

Tags: node.js, electron, recordrtc

I want to upload the recorded video at each specified time to web server. The below code upload the video to my Django web server fine. The first upload video can be played, however, the next videos can't be played. Any idea why this occur?

I have also opened an issue on Github a few months ago, but I couldn't get any solution yet. 
https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/issues/438

```
setInterval(progressive_upload, 5000);
function progressive_upload(){
  var email = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
  var tempChunk;
  console.log(recordedChunks);
  if(count != 0){
    tempChunk = recordedChunks.slice(last_blob, recordedChunks.length);
    tempChunk.unshift(recordedChunks[0]);
    console.log(tempChunk);
  }
  else {
    tempChunk = recordedChunks.slice(0, recordedChunks.length);
    console.log(tempChunk);
  }
  last_blob = recordedChunks.length;
  count += 1;
  var blob = new Blob(tempChunk, {type: "video/webm"});
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('data_blob', blob, email + '_' + count + '.' +  blob.type.split('/')[1]);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/video_upload/', true);
  xhr.send(data);
}
```

Why all uploads after the first one couldn't be played?

Answer (score 0):

I get some suggestions from others and come up with a solution to it. Below is the snippet of my code.

```
setInterval(progressive_upload, 900000);
function progressive_upload(){
  var email = document.getElementById('user_id').value;
  theRecorder.stop();
  theStream.getTracks().forEach(track => { track.stop(); });
  count += 1;
  var blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, {type: "video/webm"});
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('data_blob', blob, email + '_' + count + '.' + blob.type.split('/')[1]);
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8000/video_upload/', true);
  xhr.send(data);
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function(stream){
        theStream = stream;
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        try {
          recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {mimeType : "video/webm"});
        } catch (e) {
          console.error('Exception while creating MediaRecorder: ' + e);
          return;
        }
        recordedChunks = []
        theRecorder = recorder;
        recorder.ondataavailable = 
            (event) => {
              recordedChunks.push(event.data); 
          };
        recorder.start(100);
      })
      .catch(e => { console.error('getUserMedia() failed: ' + e); });
}
```

Hope it will help others in the future.

Comment: use ```video.srcObject  = stream``` Instead of ```video.src = URL.createObject()```